# Syntax error when add trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, database-trigger

I have procedure:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE channge_max_priority()
    BEGIN
      update feeds set max_post_priority =
        (
            select max(feed_posts.priority)
            from feed_posts
            where feed_posts.feed_id = feed_id
        )
        where feeds.id = feed_id;
    END
```

And I want to create three triggers:

```
      CREATE TRIGGER feed_post_after_test AFTER INSERT (And update and delete ) ON feed_posts
      FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE change_max_priority();
```

Procedure work correctly, but when I try start trigger - I get error:

```
Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'PROCEDURE change_max_priority()' at line 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a double `nn` in name procedure :

replace :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE channge_max_priority()
```

by

```
CREATE PROCEDURE change_max_priority()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the update statement to use a join instead, this should work:

```
update feeds 
set max_post_priority =  max(feed_posts.priority)
FROM feeds f
INNER JOIN feed_posts fp on feed_posts.feed_id = f.feed_id
Group BY f.feed_id
```

Answer (score -1):

In mysql, a procedure is executed using `CALL`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER feed_post_after_test AFTER INSERT (And update and delete ) ON feed_posts
      FOR EACH ROW CALL change_max_priority();
```

I don't see why you should execute the procedure for each row though, the whole `feeds` table is update in one procedure call.

Also not sure the last `where feeds.id = feed_id;` (just before `END`) is correct in the procedure.